# LSTM State Tuple in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

How do I use LSTMStateTuple in Tensorflow 2.0?

I am trying to implement code like the below:

```
state = rnn.LSTMStateTuple(hidden_state, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is moved to compat.v1.

```
state = rnn.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(hidden_state, output)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMStateTuple

Appearantly, they are trying to move the libraries towards new dataset system. There is:

```
tf.raw_ops.BatchDataset(
    input_dataset, batch_size, output_types, output_shapes, name=None
)
```

Instead you can use tf.keras.layers.LSTM and tf.keras.layers.RNN libraries. However, not sure you can utilize them. I wish they'd put some examples with the new libraries.